# Writing .wav file to directory in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, audio

I am writing an app with which I want to play sound and record at the same time using flutter. After the recording stopped, I want to store the file as .wav to a folder using the path_provider package (https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider).
When I stop the recording, the following function is called:

```
  if (!isRecording) return Future<bool>.value(false);
  print("Stop Listening to the microphone");
  listener.cancel();
  io.Directory tempDir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
  io.File tempFile = io.File('${tempDir.path}/audio_data.wav');
  print(tempFile);
  await tempFile.writeAsBytes(currentSamples,flush: true);
  List<int> audioList = await tempFile.readAsBytes();
  print(audioList);
  setState(() {
    isRecording = false;
    currentSamples = null;
    startTime = null;
  });
  return Future<bool>.value(true);
}
```

I get the data I want to store from the listener, which is a microphone instance from the package mic_stream (https://pub.dev/packages/mic_stream).
The data I want to write is a `List<int> currentSamples` which I get from the microphone stream from the listener. When I execute this app and stop the recording, I find a .wav in the right Directory. But this file does not contain any data unfortunately. The other way around, when I read the Bytes again from the .wav file (`List<int> audioList = await tempFile.readAsBytes();`) I get the same List that I put in before. My question: is there a better way to store a .wav file than this one? The approach was based on the following video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hMy7-X9qzo4 (around min 25). Thank you!

Comment: Is the file size 0 bytes? `I find a .wav in the right Directory` Which directory exactly? Full path please. Which Android version on device used?

Comment: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.sonar_example_app/files/audio_data.wav

Comment: Android version 10. Yes, that happens to me, the file size is 0 bytes even though I am writing bytes. That is the problem. I am getting an empty .wav file basically.